# Docker RUN layer has no mounted volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my docker-compose, I am mounting a local folder to a folder for Docker. I can see and use the mounted volume with CMD in the Dockerfile, but not with RUN. RUN seems to be a totally clean layer from the docs. Is there a way to have RUN be able to use mount points specified in the docker-compose file?

Answer (score 1):

You can't mount volumes during the `docker build` process, regardless of whether you use `docker` itself, `docker-compose`, or some other tool.  The whole idea is that the *build* process is supposed to be as indepdent of your environment as possible, so that the resulting images have no dependencies on your local system and can be more easily shared.

There are generally alternate ways of approaching whatever problem you're trying to solve that do not require trying to expose data into your build process.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there's a big difference between `CMD` and `RUN`

`CMD` is used to provide arguments or command which is execute when you start the container
`RUN` is used to provide a command to execute to create a new layer.

In short: volumes are not available during build step (when `RUN` is executed).

Docker containers have two ways of providing "external" files:

- In build step, context is passed.
- In run step, container layer + volumes are used.

See for `CMD`:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

See for `RUN`:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run

For context see:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#usage
- (docker-compose) https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build